# XCode: Empty Application won't compile, Asset Catalog Compiler Error

Tags: ios, xcode

I was going through the Apple tutorials for developing iOS apps. It tells me to open an Empty Application in XCode and run it in the iOS Simulator (I haven't even written anything yet!). I get this error:

`/Users/.../ToDoList/ToDoList/Images.xcassets: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)`

I have searched google and Stack Overflow for this error but haven't found anything.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 5.1 and iOS SDK 7.1?

Comment: I'm using version 5.0.

Comment: You need to upgrade to Xcode 5.1 or later. That should solve the issue. If you search for keyword `IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1` - many people have encountered this error. There is no fixed solution. But, you can always try cleaning, restarting and even removing all derived data for Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will update and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @raurora Upgrading to XCode 6 does the trick--no more errors. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome! Always good to use the latest IDE for iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I opened the application in Xcode 5.0.2 and its not working (the same error occurred during compile time).  There is some problem in the Xcode it seems.  I closed the Xcode and I opened in the Xcode 6.1 its working fine without any error.